# Can i use the material ui barcode scanning so ml kit without firebase in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, barcode, barcode-scanner

I would like the features and the intelligence of the google mateiral barcode scanner so Google ML Kit (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit). but i can only develop with firebase on ios or android. is there a similiar framework in mui or am i able to use a intelligent barcode scanner like the material ui barcode scanner in react?

I didnt have any code till now (for the barcode module), but have to decide with framework to use

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @starball yeah but i cant explain it any further. just wanted to know how to implement this module into a react app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.